# How to use a commit in git without adding it to your branch?

Tags: git

I have branch X - working on a task. 
Suddenly I run into a bug, and I fix it on branch Y and open a pull request.

I would like to continue work on branch X, with the changes made on branch Y but without the commit.

Is there a way to do this in git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cherry-pick the commit on branch Y to branch X, and tell it not to make a commit.

`git cherry-pick <hash> --no-commit`

Comment: sorry, I didn't see your fix )

Answer (score 4):

You can use just cherry-pick command without commit:

```
git cherry-pick <hash> --no-commit
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the changes in a stash when you are in branch Y and then apply that stash in branch X.

```
git stash save <patch_name>
```

Note: [You can do this for n number of changes. very useful feature.]

```
git checkout X

git stash apply <patch_number_you want to apply>
```

Note: [You can apply any number of patches you saved and delete if you want]